# How to remove $data stream from file in windows 8

Tags: filesystems, windows-8-preview

Windows for a while now has added an additional hidden stream to files that were downloaded from the internet.  If you attempted to use these files, you'd get all kinds of odd behavior as windows was detecting this additional stream and then preventing the app / exe from getting all sorts of security clearance.  But in previous versions of windows you could right click on a file, go to properties then click 'Unblock' which removed the extra stream.  Windows 8 seems to be doing the additional streams trick, but I haven't yet found a way to remove them using the win 8 UI.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There are >5 "Alternate Data Stream" programs that will view , and some that will remove ADS data.  These programs have worked in all the NTFS system so far. I dont know 8, but you could try "hijackthis" http://majorgeeks.com/Trend_Micro_HijackThis_d5554.html (watch which button you hit to download) In hijackthis, select "config" lower right, then go into the "misc tools" And you will find ADS spy.  I would be interested in anything you know or learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on Michael Crump's site

http://michaelcrump.net/unblock-files-in-windows-8-using-powershell-and-registry

Basically this is setting up a global menu item in the shell allowing you to call powershell to remove the extra data stream.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\powershell]
@="Unblock Files"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe Unblock-File  -LiteralPath '%L'"

Edit:  This is no longer needed as the windows explorer property pages now has the 'unblock' command as of Win 8 RTW.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8 does not use NTFS by default. It uses REFS which does not have support for named streams. Consequently no file should have an alternative data stream called $data.

Comment: Wrong.  ReFS is only available on Windows Server 8: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/16/building-the-next-generation-file-system-for-windows-refs.aspx

Comment: Fair enough. That seems like a bit of a random decision by Microsoft to build a new filesystem and then not to deploy it.

Comment: Oh, it is being deployed, but not by default.

Comment: ReFS is not a bootable file system.  Even on win8 server the boot drives will continue to be in NTFS AFAIK.